# Atlas map not found in the atlas

Tags: path-of-exile

I've had some maps that do not show up in the atlas. For example, dig as well as precinct is not highlighted when I do a search for them in the atlas screen. Although, in their descriptions (map tooltip when hovering mouse over), it's indicated that they belong to a certain region.

Is it a bug? if not, what's the point of running these maps at all since they will not progress the game?

Comment: Do you have watchstones socketed in those regions? Maps now show up / hide based on how many watchstones are socketed in each region.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud that's probably it. I don't have watch stones in all regions as of now. a side question: if a map is not visible in the atlas due to lack of watch stones in the region, if i run the map, will it progress the game? i.e. making the conquerors appear?

Comment: I believe atlas progression works but not conquerors. I'd have to look that one up though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get maps that do not appear on your atlas are non-map sources such as Zana's shop, delve and seemingly metamorphs. While in maps, the only eligible drops are the maps at the exact tier shown on the atlas screen.

To progress the atlas (i.e. spawn the conquerors), you will need to run maps at the tier they are shown at on the atlas *while* you have the minimum amount of watchstones socketed in the correct region.

Dig is a T11 map base, meaning that's when it *first* appears, which I believe is at 3 stones in its region. If you run that map with 1, 2 or 4 watchstones, it will not be eligible to spawn conquerors. It will not appear at 1 or 2 stones, and would be the wrong tier at 4 stones (you would need the T14 dig at that point).

Map completion progression/bonus objective should be unaffected as it doesn't care about watchstones, only that you kill the boss and map rarity/corruption.

Comment: in that sense, if i dont have 3 stones socketed in Dig's region, i'd never get T11 Dig map?

Comment: @Will That is correct, you would normally not get T11 Dig as a drop in that situation. (apart from the exceptions noted in the answer). You could always just trade for them if you really needed the map for atlas completion/card farming and it just never seemed to drop,